# json_encode remove quotes from keys?

Tags: php, json

If I use json_encode() on an array like this:

```
return json_encode(array( 'foo' => 'bar'));
```

The return is:

```
{'foo' : 'bar'}
```

The key is passed as a literal, and that is tripping up my script. What I really need is:

```
{ foo : 'bar' }
```

Does json_encode do that or do I have to strip the quotes out myself with some ugly regex?

Comment: Your second example is not valid JSON. The keys must be quoted strings.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When I test this portion of code :

```
echo json_encode(array( 'foo' => 'bar'));
die;
```

I get :

```
{"foo":"bar"}
```

Which is valid JSON.

*(Note these are double-quotes, and not simple-quotes as you posted)*

The ouput you are asking for :

```
{ foo : 'bar' }
```

is valid Javascript, but **is not valid JSON** -- so `json_encode` will not return that.

See [json.org](http://json.org/) for the specification of the JSON format -- which is a **subset** of Javascript, and not Javascript itself.

Instead of "*stripping the quotes out myself with some ugly regex*", you should adapt your code, so it accepts valid JSON : this is way better, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to convert your JSON to print a javascript object (that was my case) you can use ugly regex like this:

```
$myJsonString = preg_replace('/"([^"]+)"\s*:\s*/', '$1:', $myJsonString);
```

Source: https://hdtuto.com/article/php-how-to-remove-double-quotes-from-json-array-keys

Comment: Unfortunately its not just javascript - Neo4j requires it too!

Answer (score 2):

No, `json_encode` will not do this for you.  The [json specification](http://www.json.org/) specifcally requires that keys be quoted strings.  This is done to ensure that keys which are javascript reserved words won't break the data object.

Answer (score 0):

How is it tripping up your script?

And per the [JSON specification](http://json.org/), key names are *supposed* to be strings.  The 2nd snippet you posted is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone. I did not know that about the JSON spec. The issue was in fact with my script because I had not set the datatype of my $.ajax() function to "json"

What I learned today -- JSON and Javascript are not the same thing!